# Conexão Persistente ao banco de dados Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Olá gostaria de saber se eu mantiver uma conexão com banco de dados aberta(conexão persistente) é melhor do que eu fechar sempre após uma consulta?

Answer (score 6):

Isso depende muito. Várias instâncias (Manter a conexão aberta) podem ser úteis caso haja uma grande demanda contínua, ou caso o controle de acesso ao banco e operações suportadas (insert, alter, delete) seja feito por usuários do banco, ou mesmo se as requisições ao banco forem distribuídas. Em contrapartida, uma única instância, além de ser mais fácil de gerenciar, atende bem uma quantidade razoável de usuários com requisições esporádicas (o que é o caso em muitos sistemas).

Mas você fechar e abrir a conexão com o banco pode ter um custo notável em desempenho, pois os recursos gastos (tempo e processamento) para carregar o driver e acessar o banco diversas vezes pode causar uma lentidão indesejada, ainda mais se muitas requisições consecutivas sejam feitas.

Você poderia fazer um Singleton para solucionar o seu caso. Siga esse guia aqui que é muito bom:

http://www.devmedia.com.br/php-singleton-aplicando-o-padrao-de-projeto-na-pratica/28469